# nothing added to repo, still it showed some additional logs upon pull

Tags: git, github, version-control

[image]

I did a `git pull`, and observed the following logs in that.

Although there was no new commit to the repo, as the logs also say *Already up to date*

What does these logs marked as [new tag] specify ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git pull` does two things :

1. get all the new data stored in the remote (same as `git fetch`) -- this includes new commits on existing branches, new branches, new tags, deleted branches and deleted tags
2. update your active branch with its remote counterpart (same as `git merge origin/your/branch`)

The logs show the results of step `1.`, the final sentence refers to `2.` : your active branch is already up to date.